# How do I reach a specific column of sqldatareader in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am writing a method which will call a stored procedure. This stored Procedure will return a dataset which contains an attributes. I need to change the value of one particular attribute.
My code is something like this.

```
try
        {               
            cmdPendingStatus.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader pendingStatusList;
            List<string> lstPendingRequestId = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                pendingStatusList = cmdPendingStatus.ExecuteReader();
                if (pendingStatusList.HasRows)
                {
                    while (pendingStatusList.Read())
                    {
                        lstPendingRequestId.Add(pendingStatusList.GetString(0));
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: After this point i am stuck. After I add the Sqldatareader to list, Next what I want to do is reach to the element at Row 1 column 4. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
     DataSet dsStatusPending = new DataSet();
     StoredProcedure cmdPendingStatus = new StoredProcedure();
     cmdPendingStatus.ProcName = "sp_Name";
     dsStatusPending = DbManager.ExecuteDataSet(cmdPendingStatus);
     if (dsStatusPending.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
     {
          foreach (DataRow rowToInsert in dsStatusPending.Tables[0].Rows)
          {                  
              if (rowToInsert["ColumnName"] != System.DBNull.Value && rowToInsert["ColumnName"].ToString().ToUpper() == "I")
              {
                   //User Defined Code Goes Here
              }
           }
      }
```

This is how I got to the specific column.

Answer (score 1):

```html
cmdPendingStatus.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataReader pendingStatusList;
List<string> lstPendingRequestId = new List<string>();

try
{
  conn.Open();
  pendingStatusList = cmdPendingStatus.ExecuteReader();
  if (pendingStatusList.HasRows)
  {
    while (pendingStatusList.Read())
    {
      if(condition here)
      {
        lstPendingRequestId.add("NEW VALUE")
      }
      else
      {
        lstPendingRequestId.Add(pendingStatusList.GetString(0));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Column name to be specified within pendingStatusList["ColumnName"]

```
  try
            {
                conn.Open();
                pendingStatusList = cmdPendingStatus.ExecuteReader();
                if (pendingStatusList.HasRows)
                {
                    while (pendingStatusList.Read())
                    {
                        lstPendingRequestId.Add(pendingStatusList["ColumnName"]);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: No what I need to do is retrieve the whole table in the list and from there on I need to change the specified row column entry and then insert into another table.

Comment: u need to store entire table in an object ? or u need to store as table

Comment: you can use the following code to store into a table                   
            DataTable datable1 = new DataTable();
            datatable1.Load(cmdPendingStatus.ExecuteReader());

Comment: I have another stored procedure to store the values returned by passing the values to the stored procedure one by one in another table.

Comment: Is the result of 1st stored procedure has multiple columns ?

Comment: you can use nested query where the 2nd stored procedure input is the 1st stored procedure output of each row. so you should execute 2nd stored procedure within loop of output of  1st stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, the result of 1st stored procedure has multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change an attribute in ExecuteReader but you can read a value like this:

```
var value = Reader[1];
```

You can always change the value of var and write another stored procedure to save changes if that is what you want to do.